# iOS Autolayout and hugging content

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have tableViewCell with 3 views inside.
Inside each view I have several labels with text.

My purpose to make that view same width base on tableViewCell width. For example if tableViewCell width is 300, each view width will be 100.

I tryied create constrains equal widths or aspect ratio 1:1 to them all. But it did not work. How can I archive that?

Comment: There are many methods to achieve this. The easiest way is to embed all three views in a horizontal `UIStackView` set the `Distribution` to `Fill Equally`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the constraints below to make the 3 Views with equal size irrespective of the size of the container view.

**Sample** : TableViewCell with three UIView.

[image]

**View 1 Constraints:**
[image]

**View 2 Constraints :**

[image]

**View 3 Constraints :**

[image]